# Вывод текста на одной строке html

Tags: html, html5

Мне надо использовать цвета background и color. Я пишу так.

```
<div style="background-color: #8c8c8c; color: #ffffff;">hello</div>
<div style="background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;">0c0c0c</div>
```

Но текст почему то на разных строках оказывается, а мне надо чтобы на одной строке был текст. Как это сделать? div не обязательно, но главное чтобы background-color и color можно было задать и ещё шрифт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

• Обычно используют тег `<span>` для работы с текстом. У блоков `div` по умолчанию стоит `display: block;` - который переносит их на отдельную строку и дает ширину 100%. Они будут вести себя как span, если задать `display: inline;`

• CSS позволяет вынести все стили из HTML в отдельное место. Так легче работать с кодом, особенно если у вас будет много таких подкрашенных кусков. Каждый раз достаточно будет добавлять на элемент класс с нужной краской, а не весь код. Это дело добавляется где-то вверху страницы, внутри `<style> тега, здесь </style>`

• Цвет вида `#aa33bb` можно сократить до `#a3b`

Пример:

```css
.hello { 
  background-color: #888; 
  color: #fff; 
  font-family: 'Monotype Corsiva'; 
  font-size: 25px;
}

.bubu { background-color: #fff; color: #000; }
```

```html
<span class="hello">hello</span>
<span class="bubu">0c0c0c</span>

<span class="hello">1122334455</span>
<span class="bubu">0c0c0c</span>

<span class="hello">mooooo</span>
<span class="bubu">0c0c0c</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

**div** - по умолчанию блочный элемент.
Вам нужно принудительно задать ему свойство

```
display: inline-block;
```

тогда блоки будут расположены друг за другом.
Но, рекомендую Вам ознакомиться с bootstrap, это очень удобно и практично при решении вопросов с вёрсткой.
Итого:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; background-color: #8c8c8c; color: #ffffff;">hello</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;">0c0c0c</div>
```

Comment: Да я в qt делаю программу. Там надо в html тегах задать текст.